# Returning Set of Styles

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="practise.css"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="practise.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="items"><p id="help">Hello World</p></div>


        <script>
            var para=document.getElementById('help');
            var check=true;

            //want to return these styles whenever mouse is clicked
            function toggle(){
                if(check){
                            para.style.color="#EEFFCC";
                            para.style.textAlign="center";
                            para.style.fontSize="1em";
                }else{
                            para.style.color="#223311";
                            para.style.textAlign="center";
                            para.style.fontSize="4em";

                }
                check=!check;
            }

            para.onclick=toggle();

        </script>    
    </body>
</html>
```

The code i want to make is that it toggles between two sets of Styles whenever mouse is licked on 'para' element. But i couldn't figure out how to return the styles to the 'para.onclick' call below the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you are doing:

```
para.onclick = toggle();
```

which means that `para.onclick` will be the result of executing `toggle()`.

What you want to do is assign `toggle` to `para.onclick`:

```
para.onclick = toggle;
```

The difference is this:

```
function result() {
    return 2;
}
var res = result(); 
// res = 2
var fnRes = result;
// fnRes = function() { return 2; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just create a little function when you click the `onClick` it calls your toggle, like so `para.onclick = function() {}`.

```js
var para = document.getElementById('help');
var check = true;

function toggle() {
  if (check) {
    para.style.color = "blue";
    para.style.textAlign = "center";
    para.style.fontSize = "1em";
  } else {
    para.style.color = "red";
    para.style.textAlign = "center";
    para.style.fontSize = "4em";
  }
  check = !check;
}
para.onclick = function() {
  toggle()
};
```

```html
<div id="items">
  <p id="help">Hello World</p>
</div>
```